# setup dynamic routes using next js

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13, dynamic-routing, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm trying to build a Next.js application that displays a catalog of products organized by categories and subcategories. The category and subcategory data is stored in an array of objects that looks like this:

```
const categories = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Category A",
    subcategories: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Subcategory A1",
        subsubcategories: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "Sub-Subcategory A1.1",
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: "Sub-Subcategory A1.2",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Subcategory A2",
        subsubcategories: [
          {
            id: 3,
            name: "Sub-Subcategory A2.1",
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: "Sub-Subcategory A2.2",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Category B",
    subcategories: [
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Subcategory B1",
        subsubcategories: [
          {
            id: 5,
            name: "Sub-Subcategory B1.1",
          },
          {
            id: 6,
            name: "Sub-Subcategory B1.2",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Subcategory B2",
        subsubcategories: [
          {
            id: 7,
            name: "Sub-Subcategory B2.1",
          },
          {
            id: 8,
            name: "Sub-Subcategory B2.2",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I want to be able to generate dynamic paths for each product that follow the pattern category/subcategory/subsubcategory/productID. For example, if the user clicks on a product with ID 123 in Category A, Subcategory A1, and Sub-Subcategory A1.1, the URL should look like this: /category-a/subcategory-a1/sub-subcategory-a1-1/123.

The product data is stored in a separate array of objects that looks like this:

```
const products = [
  {
    id: 123,
    name: "Product A1.1.1",
    category_id: 1,
    subcategory_id: 1,
    subsubcategory_id: 1,
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    price: 9.99,
    image: "/images/product-a1-1-1.jpg",
  },]
```

category-a/subcategory-a1/sub-subcategory-a1-1/123.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

// file: `/pages/[category]/[subcategory]/[subsubcategory]/[product].js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

    const items = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Banana",
        category: 1,
        subcategory: 1,
        subsubcategory: 1,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Foobar",
        category: 2,
        subcategory: 3,
        subsubcategory: 5,
      }
    ];
    
    
    const categories = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Fruits",
        subcategories: [
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "Tropical fruits",
            subsubcategories: [
              {
                id: 1,
                name: "Berry fruits", // yes a banana is really a berry fruit
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                name: "Sub-Subcategory A1.2",
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            name: "Subcategory A2",
            subsubcategories: [
              {
                id: 3,
                name: "Sub-Subcategory A2.1",
              },
              {
                id: 4,
                name: "Sub-Subcategory A2.2",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Category B",
        subcategories: [
          {
            id: 3,
            name: "Subcategory B1",
            subsubcategories: [
              {
                id: 5,
                name: "Sub-Subcategory B1.1",
              },
              {
                id: 6,
                name: "Sub-Subcategory B1.2",
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            name: "Subcategory B2",
            subsubcategories: [
              {
                id: 7,
                name: "Sub-Subcategory B2.1",
              },
              {
                id: 8,
                name: "Sub-Subcategory B2.2",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
    
    const slugify = str =>
      str
        .toLowerCase()
        .trim()
        .replace(/[^\w\s-]/g, '')
        .replace(/[\s_-]+/g, '-')
        .replace(/^-+|-+$/g, '');
    
    export default function Product() {
    
      const router = useRouter()
    
      const { category, subcategory, subsubcategory, product } = router.query
      console.log(category, subcategory, subsubcategory, product);
      // {category: 'fruits', subcategory: 'tropical-fruits', subsubcategory: 'berry-fruits', product: 'banana'}
    
    
      const found = items.find((item) => slugify(item.name) === product); // banana === banana
      console.log({ found });
      // {id: 1, name: 'Banana', category: 1, subcategory: 1, subsubcategory: 1}
    
      return (
        <div>{found.name}</div>
      )
    }
    
    export async function getStaticPaths() {
    
      const paths = items.map((item) => {
        // find the right categories for this product item
        let categoryFound = categories.find((c) => c.id == item.category);
        let subcategoryFound = categoryFound.subcategories.find((sc) => sc.id == item.subcategory);
        let subsubcategoryFound = subcategoryFound.subsubcategories.find((ssc) => ssc.id == item.subsubcategory);
    
        return {
          params: {
            product: slugify(item.name), // the slug
            category: slugify(categoryFound.name),
            subcategory: slugify(subcategoryFound.name),
            subsubcategory: slugify(subsubcategoryFound.name)
          }
        }
      });
    
      return {
        paths,
        fallback: false,
      };
    
    }
    
    export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    
      const { category, subcategory, subsubcategory, product } = params;
    
      return {
        props: {
          category,
          subcategory,
          subsubcategory,
          product,
        },
      };
    }
```

The build process also build the product pages with the correct categories:
image

And you can open your products like so:

```
http://localhost:3000/fruits/tropical-fruits/berry-fruits/banana
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

basic idea:

1. generate `pages/` or `app/` pages BEFORE NextJs build (prepare script)
2. overthink nesting structure: subsubsub isn’t that generic, what if there are more subcategories added one day? anyway you save some code and make it more readible using recursion…

BTW I think I’m going to give NextJS that prepare proposal, it’s kinda really missing.. pages should be generated just like that.

Update: This code has no errors but isn't tested yet either:

```js
import mkdirp from "mkdirp";

type ArticleId = number;
type CategoryId = number;

interface Article {
  id: ArticleId;
  name: string;
  category: CategoryId[];
}

interface Category {
  id: CategoryId;
  name: string;
  categories?: Category[];
}

// @proposal consider a flattened structure
const articles: Article[] = [
  {
    id: 1000,
    name: "banana",
    category: [1, 1, 2],
  },
  {
    id: 2000,
    name: "strawberry",
    category: [1, 1, 1],
  },
];

// @proposal always use 'sub' or like here 'categories' (no subsubsub)
const categories: Category[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "fruits",
    categories: [
      {
        id: 11,
        name: "berries", // 
        categories: [{ id: 111, name: "swiss berries" }], // 
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        name: "bananas",
        categories: [{ id: 121, name: "argentina bananas" }], // 
      },
    ],
  },
];

const paths: string[] = [];

// Recursive function to find deepest subCategory
function recursive(category: Category, currentPath = ""): void {
  const subCategories = category.categories;

  // no subCategories found – return as path
  if (!subCategories)
    return void paths.concat([`${currentPath}/[${category.name}]`]);

  // subCategories found – step one deeper for every sub
  subCategories.forEach((subCategory) =>
    // add the new currentPath when stepping deeper to keep track of where you are
    // also wrap into [nextDynamicPathBrackets]
    recursive(subCategory, `${currentPath}/[${subCategory.name}]`)
  );
}

// Find deepest category level for every category
categories.forEach((category) => recursive(category));

// Create dynamic page structure (with productId at the end)
paths.forEach((path) => mkdirp.sync(`${path}/[productId]`));
```

The code can be optimised, as you should run it before NextJs build it's not too important for now, as no customer ever will feel that (but you will, at deployment. Depending on article amount you certainly should enhance it)

Then depending on `app/` or `pages/` you can access `req.query` at:

- `[productId]/page.tsx` (`app/` directory)
- `[productId]/index.tsx` (`pages/` directory)

...and display the correct product.

ah: you can add the `index/page.tsx` file also in the loop and just import the code where you display the product (same code for every product in every category.

BTW I had an idea regarding marketing. Everyone goes like 9.99 or 69.99... At this point just make it 10 or 70 and praise yourself with a text like "no need to .99 our prices to look better. Our prices are fair  You're welcome (please don't do it if your prices aren't fair )